# Chrome App webview behavior on chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to create editor that lets you edit and changes your website.
So in the editor, I want to show iframe with a website.

Since there are many click-jack protections against website being opened withing iframe (headers and js), I't became impossible to do for some websites.

I came across the "webview" element, in the "Chrome app" documentation,

**And I wonder, Is there any way to use "webview" or control that have the same behavior in chrome extension.**

P.S: The only access I seek is using "postMessage".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there is no way to use `<webview>` outside a Chrome App.

So in theory you could make your editor an App.

Comment: There is a way to acheive this behavior in a tab? ( not webview specificly)

Comment: Well you can load the website in a tab. You cannot frame some websites. It's unclear why exactly you wanted that in the first place.

Comment: I wanted to create optimizely.com like editor. Without using proxy or other waky solutions. The last options is an app, which is not that UX frienly since the app will be initialize thrught a website.

Comment: You can try and inject your UI inside the target page, but that's about it.